# Print DataFrame to reuse in the creation of a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently heard about the pandas [read_clipboard()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) function and it has been super useful to quickly use DataFrames from SO questions. The problem is that the DataFrame must be the last copied thing. Is there a way to for example print a DataFrame in a way that can be used to hardcode a new DataFrame. I'll try to make this a bit clearer:

Say I find this DataFrame somewhere:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

So I can copy this DataFrame and then import it in my code like this

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

But when I run this script later I have to make sure the DataFrame is the last thing I copied. What I'm looking for is a function (`print_to_reuse()`) that does something like this:

```
df.print_to_reuse()
out: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Now I could copy this output and hardcode the definition of `df` as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
```

In this way, it doesn't matter when I rerun my code and what is the last thing I copied.

I can think of a method that does the same but it seems like there should be an easier approach. I could export the copied DataFrame as a csv and then later on import this csv like this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.to_csv("path")
```

And then

```
df = read_csv("path")
use_df()
```

So basically, is there a way to do this that doesn't require making a new csv?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
df.to_dict("list")
```

Which will give:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

That you can use to run later the same script instead of `read_clipboard()`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. I should've thought of that.